# Entrypoint #FAIL - no such file or directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

In getting a django env setup, was working on how to containerize the env. In doing so, I can't get the entrypoint to work on Docker for Windows/Linux.

```
Successfully built e9cb8e009d91
Successfully tagged avengervision_web:latest
avengervision_db_1 is up-to-date
Starting avengervision_web_1 ... done
```

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             
1da83169ba41        avengervision_web      "sh /usr/src/app/ent…"   44 minutes 
STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
Exited (2) 20 seconds ago                       avengervision_web_1
```

```
docker logs 1da83169ba41
sh: can't open '/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh': No such file or directory
```

Have simplified the entrypoint.sh to just get it to execute.

Have tried

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh","/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"] & 
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Made sure the line ending in git and vscode are set to LF and ran the code through dos2unix

Ran the same Docker Compose on Windows and Linux and get the same exception on both

added to the Dockerfile as extra precaution to remove all line endings and made sure to chmod +x the script

Commented out the EntryPoint and ran docker run -tdi  and I was able to docker attach and execute the script from within the container without any issue.

*****docker-compose.yml*****

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
    #command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./main/:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    environment:
      - DEBUG=1
      - SECRET_KEY=foo
      - SQL_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
      - SQL_DATABASE=hello_django_dev
      - SQL_USER=hello_django
      - SQL_PASSWORD=hello_django
      - SQL_HOST=db
      - SQL_PORT=5432
      - DATABASE=postgres
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:11.2-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=hello_django
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=hello_django
      - POSTGRES_DB=hello_django_dev

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

*****Dockerfile*****

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.7-alpine

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment varibles
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install psycopg2
RUN apk update \
    && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    && apk add postgresql-dev \
    && pip install psycopg2 \
    && apk del build-deps

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pipenv
COPY ./docker/Pipfile /usr/src/app/Pipfile
RUN pipenv install --skip-lock --system --dev

# copy entrypoint.sh
COPY ./docker/entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
#RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh

# copy project
COPY main /usr/src/app/main
COPY manage.py /usr/src/app
#RUN /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh

RUN sed -i 's/\r$//' /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh  && \  
        chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh

# run entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["sh","/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

*****entrypoint.sh*****

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$DATABASE" = "postgres" ]
then
    echo "Waiting for postgres..."

    while ! nc -z $SQL_HOST $SQL_PORT; do
      sleep 0.1
    done

    echo "PostgreSQL started"
fi

echo "Testing"
#python /usr/src/app/manage.py flush
#python /usr/src/app/manage.py migrate
#python /usr/src/app/manage.py collectstatic --no-input --clear

exec "$@"
```

The goal in the end is that the container would be up and running with the django application created.

Comment: Have you created the directory `/usr/src/app`? I see the WORKDIR command. However, I think you need something like `RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app`

Comment: Thanks for the reply!!! Your question sparked an edit, I was able to docker attach to the image after commenting out the ENTRYPOINT above and the directory already exists and was able to execute the script from within the container without any issue. Sorry that I didn't have that clarified before.

Comment: `FROM python:3.7-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
RUN /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//' /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh  && \  
        chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
# run entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["sh","/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]`

Comment: Great, so everything works now? Or did you get an error after that? And my pleasure.

Comment: No @ScottSkiles that didn't fix it, just updated my post with more info that the directory does exist and running the script within the container works, just not using ENTRYPOINT, it still fails.

Comment: Can you update the post to more clearly indicate why it is still failing? Do you need/want to use ENTRY POINT? If so what's the error

Comment: got it resolved @ScottSkiles. It appears in my over zealousness in getting a clean directory structure setup, it did not work. I came across this repo and followed their directory structure and now it works as I was expecting - https://github.com/testdrivenio/django-on-docker/tree/master/app . Still not sure why the layout didn't work.

Comment: Your `volumes:` declaration hides everything that's in `/usr/src/app` in the image.  If your host system doesn't happen to have a `./main/entrypoint.sh` script then you'll get this error.  Scanning what you've posted, the paths in various places don't match up, and I'd suggest just deleting this `volumes:` block.

Comment: When I attached to the container though, I was able to see all the files for the django app in /usr/src/app including the entrypoint.sh @DavidMaze. So are you saying I could see the files, but the docker system would not? I was able to get it resolved, but it bugs me that I don't know root cause.

Comment: FYI, I still had this original problem statement on my linux box as it bugged me this didn't work. I removed all the images and containers. took out the volumes statement that @DavidMaze mentioned , and uncommented my python statements and sure enough it worked!!!

Now in my solution below it worked with the Volumes statement included, so I will need to research more on what is happening here with the directory structure so that I can go back to the original layout.

Answer (score 0):

In leveraging the layout listed here - https://github.com/testdrivenio/django-on-docker it worked. The difference in what I was doing is I created a new docker directory at the root and then had docker compose leverage that. Everything seemed to copy into the container as it was supposed to, but for some reason the EntryPoint would not work. Without changing any of the code other than updating the references to the new file locations, everything worked. Below were the changes made:

```
web:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
```

to

```
web:
    build: ./app
```

and then changing the directory structure from

```
Project Layout:
├───.vscode
├───docker
│   └───Dockerfile
│   └───entrypoint.sh
│   └───Pipfile
│   └───nginx
└───main
    ├───migrations
    ├───static
    │   └───images
    ├───templates
├───Artwork
├───django-env
│   ├───Include
│   ├───Lib
│   └───Scripts
└───docker-compose.yml
└───managy.py
```

to

```
Project Layout:
├───.vscode
├───app
│   └───main
│       ├───migrations
│       ├───static
│       │   └───images
│       ├───templates
│   └───Dockerfile
│   └───entrypoint.sh
│   └───managy.py
│   └───Pipfile
├───Artwork
├───django-env
│   ├───Include
│   ├───Lib
│   └───Scripts
└───nginx
└───docker-compose.yml
```